# 301 redirect using httpd.conf

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I read somewhere that using .htaccess for 301 redirect is not recommended and that a better practice will be to use httpd.conf

1. is that true ? why ?
2. can we use regexp in httpd.conf - the same as we do with .htaccess ?

Comment: @BookOfZeus I'm sorry I didn't save the link. I've done some reading about options for 301 redirect yesterday and one of the posts mentioned that as a fact - without providing an explanation. Assuming that I have access to both httpd.conf and .htaccess, is it indeed a better practice using httpd.conf ?

Comment: Another link that I found: http://www.seomoz.org/learn-seo/redirection also says that the default should be using httpd.conf - but they don't explain why...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, generally speaking **.htaccess is just meant for per-directory settings and the httpd.conf for server wide settings**. Also accessing the `.htaccess` file adds some small overhead but that's probably not your concern.

And yes, you can `use regular expressions in the httpd.conf`

Comment: some wiseguy keeps deleting comment from this post. is there a way to call a moderator to prevent it ? the last deleted comment was: @ssh - can you provide an example of using regexp in httpd.conf for 301 redirect, and does the location of the XML-tag in the file matter ?

Comment: You can actually just copy the section from the .htaccess file and put it into the httpd.conf. You might just have to add a leading slash `/` if you dont put the rules into a `<Directory>` block.